# clearInterval does not reset the setinterval value

Tags: javascript

I'm making a slot machine simulator to learn javascript and messing around with `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`. To simulate the slow stopping of the rows I set a`setTimeout()` to clear the Intervals of my 3 columns, but the timer doesn't reset the function is still called, I also tried a console log inside the setTimeout and the calls are correct 1sec after 2sec another log and then the third. what I'm doing wrong?
Here try the game and the full code with HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/orphtv1m/1/

````
            //Here i initialize my setInterval
            wheelIntervals[i] = setInterval(function(){
                columns[i][numberStart[i]].style.background = "white";
                numberStart[i] = (numberStart[i]+1)<10 ? numberStart[i]+1 : 0;
                columns[i][numberStart[i]].style.background = "red";
            },timer);
/*Code*/
        setTimeout(function(){
            //Here i try to clear it
            console.log('Helo');
            clearInterval(wheelIntervals[i]);
        },i*1000);
    }
    setTimeout(endGame(), 3000);
}); ```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Remove from the posted code anything that is not related to the issue.

Comment: By the time `clearInterval` is called `i` has become 3 so you are calling  `clearInterval(wheelIntervals[3])` 3 times. You need to extract `setTimeout` to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clearInterval(wheelInterval[i])
```

Will be always called with i equal to 2
Using `setTimeout` inside loops might be a little bit tricky because of closures.
Here is an explanation how to do it correctly: https://medium.com/@axionoso/watch-out-when-using-settimeout-in-for-loop-js-75a047e27a5f

Comment: Wow didn't know this behavior thanks so much, solved for now declaring with let in the for loop after I will extract in a function